# Dynamic height 100% td for email

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

In a context of table emailing. I'm looking for an dynamic height width image of my cell column, the unknown height is defined dynamically by my content in rowspan:

```css
* {padding: 0;}
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
img {width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
```

```html
<table width="300">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="20" width="100%"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20" height="20">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" />
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="260" align="top">
      my content dynamic<br />
      my content dynamic<br />
      my content dynamic<br />
      my content dynamic<br />
      my content dynamic<br />
      my content dynamic
    </td>
    <td width="20" height="20">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20" height="100%">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8zxDxHwAFtQJYX0yrrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
      </td>
    <td width="20" height="100%">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8zxDxHwAFtQJYX0yrrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In my example, It's the 2 pinks columns that I want with height 100%. It's for an email so I can't use position absolute or JS trick's (according to the [caniuse for email](https://caniuse.email/) for cover a maximum of clients)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the pink cells a `bgColor` attribute.

```css
* {padding: 0;}
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
img {width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
```

```html
<table width="300">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="20" width="100%"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" /></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td width="20" height="20">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" />
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="260" align="top">
      my content dynamic<br /> my content dynamic<br /> my content dynamic<br /> my content dynamic<br /> my content dynamic<br /> my content dynamic
    </td>
    <td width="20" height="20">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20" bgColor="#ff0458">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8zxDxHwAFtQJYX0yrrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
    </td>
    <td width="20" bgColor="#ff0458">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8zxDxHwAFtQJYX0yrrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```